# Frequency of an Array using Hashmaps and Objects

Tags: javascript

**As you will notice, I'm trying to analyze which value will occur the most frequent within a given array using hashmaps and objects.** If you can, please try to identify the answer for each algorithm (hashmap and object).

The below example uses hashmaps to "map" various objects with each other. However, I am having two problems: 1. I can't increment occurrence properly: after occurrence variable is equal to 1, then that value remains forever hence the algorithm provides the wrong mode. 2. I don't know how to change the value of a map *after* the iteration is completed.

```
var highestFrequency = (array) => {
  var occurenceStored = new Map();
  let occurrence = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var j = i + 1;
    if (array[i] === array[j]){
      occurrence += 1;
      occurenceStored.set(array[i], occurrence)
    }
  }

  console.log(occurenceStored);
}


highestFrequency([101, 104, 108, 108, 111, 119, 119, 119])
```

Instead of using a hashmap, I decided to use an object instead but I fall into the same problem. The occurrence variable is permanently equal to 1. I tried declaring the occurrence variable at different places but can't seem to find the right fix.

```
var highestFrequency = (array) => {
  var occurenceStored = {};
  let occurrence = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var j = i + 1;
    if (array[i] === array[j]){
      occurenceStored[array[i]] = occurrence;
    }
  }

  console.log(occurenceStored);
}


highestFrequency([101, 104, 108, 108, 111, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120])
```

Comment: how about doing that with `reduce` method? `array.reduce((a, e)=>(a[e] = a[e] || 0, a[e]++, a),{})`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the Map, then you can do in this way:

```js
const highestFreq = (array) => {
  let myMap = new Map();
  for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    if (myMap[array[i]]) myMap[array[i]]++;
    else myMap[array[i]] = 1; 
  }
  return myMap;
}

const myArray = [101, 104, 108, 108, 111, 119, 119, 119];

const myMap = highestFreq(myArray);
console.log(myMap);
```

myMap contains the key value pair, where key are the unique elements from the given array and the mapped values are their occurences.

Answer (score 2):

Using Object way , you can achieve like below:

```
var highestFrequency = (array) => {
  var occurenceStored = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    
    if (occurenceStored[array[i]]){
      occurenceStored[array[i]] = occurenceStored[array[i]]+1;
    } else{
        occurenceStored[array[i]]=1;
    }
  }

  console.log(occurenceStored);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you only want the **most frequent** value (what if there are two different values with the same frequency ?):

- increment a counter per value
- when iterating, if a counter is greater thatn your biggest counter, make it the biggest instead.

```
const highestFreq = arr => {
  const best = { value: 0, n: 0 } // what to do if empty array ??
  arr.reduce((m, el) => {
    const counter = (m.get(el) || 0) + 1
    if (counter > best.n) {
      best.value = el
      best.n = counter
    }
    return m.set(el, counter)
  }, new Map())
  return best // or compute your frequency: best.n / arr.length
}

console.log(highestFreq([101, 104, 108, 108, 111, 119, 119, 119]))
```